# SSRS: Set layout properties group (BorderStyle, BorderWidth, Padding,...) at once

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, visual-studio-2015

I'm starting to use SSRS and would like to start my project on a clean manner and easy to change in a future the style of the report.

So I'm declaring several parameters for each layout properties (font-family, fonz-size, color, border-style, border-width,....) and would like to know if it's possible to do "merge some" :

[image]

instead of doing this for each property :

[image]

This would be more efficient and easy to set. But Visual Studio (2015 version) doesn't allow me to do it.

In CSS we can do "padding : 10px 5px 2px 4px" or "padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 5px...." (other possiblities but wanted to show here only the corresponding).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !!
For example, I want to set the border color for property Left,Right,Top,Bottom at once :

1. Declare a parameter `TableBody_BorderColor_LRTB`.
2. In "General" check "Allow multiple values"
3. In "Default Values", select "Specific values
4. Click to "Add" 4 times for the 4 values
   By our custom convention, the first value will refer to Left (L is at the first position of LRTB), the 4th value will refer to Bottom

Then select the body of the tablix, and in the BorderColor property write :
`Black; =Parameters!TableBody_BorderColor_LRTB.Value(0); =Parameters!TableBody_BorderColor_LRTB.Value(1); =Parameters!TableBody_BorderColor_LRTB.Value(2); =Parameters!TableBody_BorderColor_LRTB.Value(3)`
The "Black" is for the default Color. 
And then we select the first value `Value(0)` that is assigned to Left, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - you just need to put a comma between each.
Copy and paste this into the top level padding property:

```
=Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value, 19pt, =Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value, =Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value
```

and then expand that property - you will see that padding right has been set.

Comment: Thanks it's better but not exactly what I was looking for. I was not clear enough sorry. In fact I would like to define one general padding property containing all 4 values. Like `=Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value` which can contains all 4 values. My goal is to have as less parameter for a maximum flexibility of layout properties.

Comment: P.S: The correct syntax is `=Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value; 19pt; =Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value; =Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value` as ";" is the right separator. But this is still using 4 parameters (accept I would need 4 different values of padding)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately when you select all the entities (i.e rows within a taxlib) that have different properties the Padding options for Left, Right, Top and Bottom will disappear. In order to do this, you will need to copy the formatting to a notepad. Then clear all formatting from the existing select all and then simply copy and paste. It's very daunting, but I have found that there is no other way sadly.